# Problem on run mysql with arguments from own script

Tags: 14.04, bash, xubuntu, mysql

I have installed Xubuntu 16.04 and mysql 5.7 server.

I create simple script with name `mysql-wrapper`:

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u myuser -pmypwd mydatabase --table $*
```

Now I run command and it execute successfully:

```
mysql-wrapper -e "STATUS"
```

Then I try run next command (with space):

```
mysql-wrapper -e "SHOW TABLES"
```

I get problem: mysql print me help for commands, like I run mysql with illegal command.

How I can solve my issue?
Or may be better use alias?

Comment: Try the command between single quotes. `mysql-wrapper -e "'SHOW TABLES'"`

Comment: I try: \"..\" and '"...'" and '\"...\"' and \"'...'\", now success :-(

Comment: `-pmypwd` will show your password plain text in the process lists. You probably are getting the safety warning they added (mysql disabled the `-pmypwd` method in 5.6 or 5.7). Use `my,cnf` to store the password. Besides that: "STATUS" always works, but "SHOW TABLES" only works when you have set a database.

Comment: @Rinzwind, yes I can config user in my.cnf, but anyway I have some specific argument for all scripts (for example: --table, in future I can add anything else). I use mydatabase in common script. Anyway you try run: mysql-wrapper -e "STATUS;STATUS;" - it's work. But next not work: mysql-wrapper -e "STATUS; STATUS;"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In ordinary usage, you shouldn't have any reason for using a plain `$*`. You should always be using `"$@"` (note that the quotes are included):

```
#!/bin/bash
mysql -u myuser -pmypwd mydatabase --table "$@"
```

Only with `"$@"` will your script arguments pe passed as-is to the command, this is safe from field splitting and globbing.

To see the difference, run a script containing

```
#!/bin/bash
printf "%s\n" $*
printf "%s\n" $@
printf "%s\n" "$*"
printf "%s\n" "$@"
```

with various arguments.